# build simple template html - divs

Tags: html, css

I'm new with DIV's and I would like to build a simple template for my website.
I need the **header** to be fixed and 100%, **left panel** for menu 200px, **right panel** for main 100% div and **bottom** panel.
I need that if the left panel doesn't show that the main will be 100%. now if it show's the "main" div in under the left panel. 10X

```
    <div id="top_menu"></div>
    <div id="left_menu"></div>
    <div id="main"></div>
    <div id="bottom"></div>


#top_menu{
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #343B43;
    width:100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 20;
}
#left_menu{
    margin-top:40px;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    background: #F4F4F4;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
}
#main{
    margin-top:40px;
    float: right;
    background:red;
    padding:30px;
    width: 90%;
}
#bottom{
    height:30px;
    position: fixed;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: put this code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so that its easier to show what you have done so far & it also helps other to help you more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your HTML and CSS like below.

HTML

```
<div id="top_menu"></div>
<div class="distab">
   <div id="left_menu"></div>
   <div id="main"></div>
</div>
<div id="bottom"></div>
```

CSS

```
#top_menu{
height: 40px;
background-color: #343B43;
width:100%;
position: fixed;
z-index: 20;
}
.distab{display:table; table-layout:fixed;}
#left_menu{
margin-top:40px;
width: 200px;
background: #F4F4F4;
z-index: 10;
display:table-cell;
}
#main{
margin-top:40px;
background:red;
padding:30px;
width: 100%;
display:table-cell;
box-sizing:border-box;
}
#bottom{
height:30px;
position: fixed;
width:100%;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9wrfm/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="top_menu"></div>
<div id="content">
  <div id="left_menu"></div>
  <div id="main"></div>
</div>
<div id="bottom"></div>

#top_menu{
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #343B43;
    width:100%;
    position: fixed;
}

#lineContainer{
  overflow: hidden; /* clear the float */
}

#left_menu{
  margin-top:40px;
  float: left;
  max-width: 200px;
  background: #F4F4F4;
}

#main{
  margin-top:40px;
  background:red;
  padding:30px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#bottom{
  height:30px;
  width:100%;
}
```

Demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/msankhala/Ck7pe/3

http://jsfiddle.net/msankhala/Ck7pe/3/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0):

for this you have to put your left menu and main under one div & put leftMenu to the height of 20% and then you will see that main had automatically taken remaining area of its parent div and when leftMenu get disappeared main will automatically take the full 100% area.

You can use Javascript for disappearing purpose but jquery is best to do this all task.